# Can you say "go greater?"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm just *wondering* if you can actually say this in certain contexts. I thought of this just recently and I thought it sounded strange, mainly because I could only think of one time you'd ever say this.

My idea was that if you wanted to tell someone "Improve yourself!" or "Get better!", then you could also *maybe* say "Go greater!"

English is my native language, and I don't see a grammatical problem with this statement (besides the lack of a noun, but then again "Get Well!" doesn't have one.) But, I've never heard it before, and I would like to know if anyone else thinks it *could* be said, and doesn't have some kind of "incorrectness" that I can't see.

Comment: You could say 'become greater' or 'get greater', these are verbs used for a change of state. 'Go' isn't used for a change of state, it's used for motion away. You can 'get better' but 'go better' would mean (if someone said it) perform the action of going better, maybe by going faster, or without bumping into things. Similarly 'go well' does not mean to go from a state of being unwell to a state of being well. Interestingly, however, you can use 'go from state to state' as I just have, but you must specify that you're talking about a transition from state to state, 'go' does not itself mean it

Comment: Thanks for your input! I agree with the "Go better" example, it doesn't make sense to me. When I hear "go greater," my first thought is going from an okay state to a greater one. I will admit, it'd be better to say "Go/ Strive for greater things" which is kinda where I got it from.

Comment: There is nothing grammatically wrong with "Go greater", although I've never heard anyone say it. It also presumes an ongoing conversation in which one has already said, "Go great,"  which is analogous to the more common expression, "Go big."

Comment: I haven't heard *Go big* more than two times in my life; I would stick more grammatical phases like *Get better*.

Comment: “This isn't working for me. We're not selling the product right here. We need to go bigger, go greater, go more. We need a motorbike flying through a burning church ridden by a lion in a Dementor suit!”

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a subject is not a problem. In English, commands and requests are called "imperative sentences", and they do not have a subject, because the subject is assumed to be the person you are talking to. Like, "Get out of here now!", clearly I mean that the person I am yelling at should get out.

That said, "Go greater" is not something I recall ever hearing someone say. Understood literally, I guess it would mean that you encourage the person to "go" in a superior way. It could be comparable to "Go faster" or "Climb higher". If you're looking for a slogan for your company or team, it's not bad. If I saw an ad for sporting goods with a slogan "Go greater!" and pictures of their products, I don't think I'd balk at that.

But it's not something people say, so you would be trying to invent a new slogan. If you just want to give general encouragement, I'd stick with an existing catch phrase or something that makes obvious literal sense. Like, "Work harder", "Do your best", etc. Depending on just what the context is.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, as least, you can say pretty much anything you want -- it doesn't have to be "approved" by anyone.  So if "Go greater!" is meaningful to the audience you're addressing then go ahead and use it.

But, in terms of comprehension, it depends greatly on context.  "Go greater", outside of any contextual framework, is a pretty meaningless phrase.  If you want a phrase that means "excel", then "shoot for the stars" or "do your best" or even "Excelsior!" would be better understood by most audiences.

However, it's conceivable that you might give a talk along the lines of "You need to excel in what you do.  Don't just settle for 'great' -- go greater!"  In such a context, while it would likely turn the stomach of many here, "go greater" would be a reasonably appropriate way to imply something superlative to simply "great".

Comment: You might run into copyright issues, however, if you adopted the slogan "Go greater (and leave the driving to us)."

Comment: Thank you all for the input. My reason for asking was because I was considering using it as a sort of slogan, and just wanted to make sure it wouldn't be too strange to read. "Go Greater" has a very specific context to it that makes it fit better than "Work Harder" as @Jay mentioned. So for now, I'll stick with it and embrace the phrase, since there doesn't seem to be anything horribly incorrect about it.

Comment: @MickAshton  - it's the sort of thing that offends purists, but especially as a advertising catchphrase, were oddities are expected if not encouraged, it should be reasonably OK.